# Pass down a component with props

Tags: reactjs

My main `Home` component renders different content based on conditions.

I need for the `<SearchPanel />` component to pass the `user` as a prop but I also need the `user` data in the `Layout` component.

This code works fine but I don't think it is correct to send the `user` twice as props.
How can I change that?

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AuthConsumer>
        {({ user }) => {
          if (!user) {
            return <ErrorPage />;
          }
          if (!user.roles.includes('Admin') && !user.roles.includes('Observer')) {
            return <Layout pageContent={<NoAccessPanel />} user={user} />;
          }
          return <Layout pageContent={<SearchPanel user={user}/>} user={user} />; //not sure about this
        }}
      </AuthConsumer>
    );
  }
}
```

`Layout` component:

```
export default function Layout({ pageContent, user }) {
  return (
    <div css={bodyWrap}>
      <Header appName="Test" user={user} />
      {pageContent}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for Layout?

Comment: @jdc91 The code for `Layout` is on the question.

Comment: Why do you think it's 'incorrect' to send the user down twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many components that are supposed to receive user context, they should be context consumers. This is a use case for higher-order component:

```
const withUser = Comp => props => (
  <AuthConsumer>
    {({ user }) => <Comp user={user} ...props/>}
  </AuthConsumer>
);
```

`Home`, `Header` and `SearchPanel` are supposed to be augmented with `withUser(...)` and receive `user` prop this way, e.g.:

*header-module.js*

```
export class Header ... 

export default withUser(Header);
```

While `Layout` doesn't use user context itself and doesn't need to receive it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you be able to add a bit more of explanation, I don't fully understand it. Thank you.

Comment: I added some explanation. I'm not sure how deep it should be. If you're not aware of HOC pattern, consider checking https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-pass-unrelated-props-through-to-the-wrapped-component first.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't do the test in the `Layout` component ? :

`Home` Component:

```js
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AuthConsumer>
        {({ user }) => {
          if (!user) {
            return <ErrorPage />;
          }
          return <Layout user={user} />
        }}
      </AuthConsumer>
    );
  }
}
```

`Layout` Component:

```js
export default function Layout({ user }) {
  return (
    <div css={bodyWrap}>
      <Header appName="Test" user={user} />
      {
        (!user.roles.includes('Admin') && !user.roles.includes('Observer'))
        ? <NoAccessPanel />
        : <SearchPanel user={user}/>
      }
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```